# What's counts as "taking active part in the hostilities" under the Geneva Convention?

Tags: laws-of-war, geneva-convention

The [Geneva Convention relative to the Protection of Civilian Persons in Time of War](https://www.ohchr.org/en/instruments-mechanisms/instruments/geneva-convention-relative-protection-civilian-persons-time-war) states that

> Persons taking no active part in the hostilities, including members of armed forces who have laid down their arms and those placed hors de combat by sickness, wounds, detention, or any other cause, shall in all circumstances be treated humanely ...

In the comments to [an answer to another question](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/88048/7410), there were questions as to the definition there. When is a soldier taking "active part" in the hostilities?

Are they considered to take an active part when they are sleeping? Awake but eating dinner? Does it matter if they are armed at the time, or merely "in uniform"? Are there (other) times when a uniformed member of the military would not be considered "taking active part" in the hostilities? Or are they considered to be taking an active part simply by being a uniformed member of a belligerent party?

Comment: The document title shows it refers to the treatment of **Civilian Persons**, and this clause shows that some members of the armed forces should be treated as if they are civilians. "Or other causes" doesn't include soldiers on a rest break. It is not about how soldiers in general should be treated, but about soldiers who have effectively ceased to be soldiers.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's the question, though. At what point have soldiers effectively ceased to be soldiers? The main phrasing "taking no active part in the hostilities" could potentially be read to include sleeping soldiers (similarly to a sick person, a sleeping person isn't doing any active soldiering while sleeping). Is that an accurate reading? How does the international community actually interpret this directive? (Note I'd personally assume that sleeping soldiers are indeed not included, but as I don't know for certain, I feel it's a valid question to ask.)

Comment: No: they are still soldiers, not (effectively) civilians for the purposes of this document. It is about soldiers who should *no longer* be considered as such, not those alternating between ssoldier and not-soldier.

Comment: @WeatherVane You seem confident in that assessment, so I encourage you to write it up as a full answer.

Comment: The question is trivial. It doesn't require a definition of soldier, but defines what a civilian is.

Comment: @WeatherVane article three is common to all of the Geneva conventions.  It's not about whether a soldier has ceased to be a soldier but about establishing a baseline of humane treatment that parties to the convention must apply to combatants _who aren't otherwise afforded the protections of the convention because the combat isn't "international in character."_

Answer (score 11):

### Members of the armed forces who are not [hors de combat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hors_de_combat) are taking an “active part”

Hors de combat is not there for padding - its a defined term of the Convention:

> A person is hors de combat if:
>
> (a) he is in the power of an adverse Party;
>
> (b) he clearly expresses an intention to surrender; or
>
> (c) he has been rendered unconscious or is otherwise incapacitated by wounds or sickness, and therefore is incapable of defending himself;
>
> provided that in any of these cases he abstains from any hostile act and does not attempt to escape.

A person is *not* hors de combat simply because they are:

- Sleeping
- Eating
- Unarmed
- Out of uniform
- Defecating
- Fornicating
- Drunk

Comment: But someone who is asleep is clearly rendered unconscious and therefore is incapable of defending themselves.

Comment: @OrangeDog "he has been rendered unconscious...by wounds or sickness"

Comment: @OrangeDog even if you don't accept that "by wounds or sickness" applies to "has been rendered unconscious," a sleeping person has not been rendered unconscious.  To be rendered unconscious is to be made unconscious by something external.  Falling asleep is not external.

Comment: @OrangeDog  Unconsciousness is the state from which you can not be roused.  Sleeping is the state in which you can be.

Comment: @Mary No, unconscious is the state of being not awake and aware of and responding to one's environment - normal sleep fulfils that definition.

Comment: @Mary keep in mind that the legal definition of unconsciousness isn't necessarily the same as the medical or physiological definition -- and even the legal definition may be different in different contexts.  The word "unconscious" might include "asleep" for some laws but not for others.

Comment: Can we have some legal reference then for what "unconscious" means and whether sleep counts?

Comment: @OrangeDog: I'm not sure there is any "official" definition of "unconscious" WRT the Geneva convention - however I'd say in this case the *context* makes this clear. The Convention does not just say "unconscious", it says "rendered unconscious  [...] by wounds or sickness" - this clearly excludes normal, healthy sleep.

Comment: @sleske except I read it as "(rendered unconscious) or (is otherwise incapacitated by wounds or sickness)". That's why we need an actual referenced answer not "obviously it means this if you're a lawyer".

Comment: @OrangeDog you seem to ignore phoog's statement that "To be **rendered** unconscious is to be made unconscious by something **external**. Falling asleep is not external."

Comment: Completely drunk person is certainly _incapacitated by ... sickness_. Because being poisoned is certainly considered a sickness.